# Extra variables in POST for Paypal IPN / button?

Tags: php, paypal

I've come across countless tutorials but all differ in some way so I'm not really sure which route I should follow.

I have an old website that needs payments to be integrated: currently, a user would fill in a form and click submit - this will post to another page that handles the updating of the database and emails the user that everything is valid.

However, I have to change it so that when the user fills in the form and clicks submit, they would have to pay via paypal - the amount to pay is the base_price * the amount of user fields filled in (i.e. count(array_filter($_POST["users"])); ).

Currently, when the user submits the form, I do the validation then post to "payment.php" page. Which is just a page displaying the values from _POST showing the user details and how much it will cost. Then I have a simple non-hosted Paypal Button for "Buy Now" (I think the hosted version will work just fine too if I just add quantity in the form but I figured I'd try the non-hosted, un-secure version for the moment).

Clicking on that button takes the user to Paypal where they can fill in their details.

What I don't understand is IPN and how I can integrate it. The original form POSTs about 10 input values, can I add those in my POST to Paypal so that after payment, the database would be updated with those values? Or would I need to update the database prior to posting to Paypal and then just add a column "verified" that I update once the user has paid?

I've set "rm" value="2" to use POST.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IPN is a behind the scenes feature.  Once the transaction complets, PayPal will send a POST of the transaction details back to your IPN script.  You read the values and do a POST back to PayPal to verify that it came from PayPal.  Then PayPal confirms if it is valid or not.  Then based on that response you can do what ever you need to with transaction details that were posted to your script.  The example below is a PHP example for an IPN script.

```
<?php

// Revision Notes
// 11/04/11 - changed post back url from https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr to https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
// For more info see below:
// https://www.x.com/content/bulletin-ip-address-expansion-paypal-services
// "ACTION REQUIRED: if you are using IPN (Instant Payment Notification) for Order Management and your IPN listener script is behind a firewall that uses ACL (Access Control List) rules which restrict outbound traffic to a limited number of IP addresses, then you may need to do one of the following: 
// To continue posting back to https://www.paypal.com  to perform IPN validation you will need to update your firewall ACL to allow outbound access to *any* IP address for the servers that host your IPN script
// OR Alternatively, you will need to modify  your IPN script to post back IPNs to the newly created URL https://ipnpb.paypal.com using HTTPS (port 443) and update firewall ACL rules to allow outbound access to the ipnpb.paypal.com IP ranges (see end of message)."


/////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////Begin Script below./////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////

// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
}
// post back to PayPal system to validate
$header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";

// If testing on Sandbox use:
//$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

$fp = fsockopen ('ssl://ipnpb.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);


// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$business = $_POST['business'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$mc_gross = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$receiver_id = $_POST['receiver_id'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$num_cart_items = $_POST['num_cart_items'];
$payment_date = $_POST['payment_date'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$payment_type = $_POST['payment_type'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_gross = $_POST['payment_gross'];
$payment_fee = $_POST['payment_fee'];
$settle_amount = $_POST['settle_amount'];
$memo = $_POST['memo'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
$txn_type = $_POST['txn_type'];
$payer_status = $_POST['payer_status'];
$address_street = $_POST['address_street'];
$address_city = $_POST['address_city'];
$address_state = $_POST['address_state'];
$address_zip = $_POST['address_zip'];
$address_country = $_POST['address_country'];
$address_status = $_POST['address_status'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$tax = $_POST['tax'];
$option_name1 = $_POST['option_name1'];
$option_selection1 = $_POST['option_selection1'];
$option_name2 = $_POST['option_name2'];
$option_selection2 = $_POST['option_selection2'];
$for_auction = $_POST['for_auction'];
$invoice = $_POST['invoice'];
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
$notify_version = $_POST['notify_version'];
$verify_sign = $_POST['verify_sign'];
$payer_business_name = $_POST['payer_business_name'];
$payer_id =$_POST['payer_id'];
$mc_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$mc_fee = $_POST['mc_fee'];
$exchange_rate = $_POST['exchange_rate'];
$settle_currency  = $_POST['settle_currency'];
$parent_txn_id  = $_POST['parent_txn_id'];
$pending_reason = $_POST['pending_reason'];
$reason_code = $_POST['reason_code'];


// subscription specific vars

$subscr_id = $_POST['subscr_id'];
$subscr_date = $_POST['subscr_date'];
$subscr_effective  = $_POST['subscr_effective'];
$period1 = $_POST['period1'];
$period2 = $_POST['period2'];
$period3 = $_POST['period3'];
$amount1 = $_POST['amount1'];
$amount2 = $_POST['amount2'];
$amount3 = $_POST['amount3'];
$mc_amount1 = $_POST['mc_amount1'];
$mc_amount2 = $_POST['mc_amount2'];
$mc_amount3 = $_POST['mcamount3'];
$recurring = $_POST['recurring'];
$reattempt = $_POST['reattempt'];
$retry_at = $_POST['retry_at'];
$recur_times = $_POST['recur_times'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

//auction specific vars

$for_auction = $_POST['for_auction'];
$auction_closing_date  = $_POST['auction_closing_date'];
$auction_multi_item  = $_POST['auction_multi_item'];
$auction_buyer_id  = $_POST['auction_buyer_id'];



//DB connect creds and email 
$notify_email =  "MyEmail@MySite.com";         //email address to which debug emails are sent to
$DB_Server = "MyServer"; //your MySQL Server
$DB_Username = "MyDBuser"; //your MySQL User Name
$DB_Password = "MyDMpassword"; //your MySQL Password
$DB_DBName = "MyDatabase"; //your MySQL Database Name


if (!$fp) {
// HTTP ERROR
} else {
fputs ($fp, $header . $req);
while (!feof($fp)) {
$res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {



//create MySQL connection
$Connect = @mysql_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password)
or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());


//select database
$Db = @mysql_select_db($DB_DBName, $Connect)
or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysql_error(). "<br>" . mysql_errno());


$fecha = date("m")."/".date("d")."/".date("Y");
$fecha = date("Y").date("m").date("d");

//check if transaction ID has been processed before
$checkquery = "select txnid from paypal_payment_info where txnid='".$txn_id."'";
$sihay = mysql_query($checkquery) or die("Duplicate txn id check query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
$nm = mysql_num_rows($sihay);
if ($nm == 0){

//execute query



    if ($txn_type == "cart"){
    $strQuery = "insert into paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,country,mc_gross,mc_fee,memo,paymenttype,paymentdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,datecreation) values ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_street."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."','".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')";

     $result = mysql_query($strQuery) or die("Cart - paypal_payment_info, Query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
     for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_cart_items; $i++) {
         $itemname = "item_name".$i;
         $itemnumber = "item_number".$i;
         $on0 = "option_name1_".$i;
         $os0 = "option_selection1_".$i;
         $on1 = "option_name2_".$i;
         $os1 = "option_selection2_".$i;
         $quantity = "quantity".$i;

         $struery = "insert into paypal_cart_info(txnid,itemnumber,itemname,os0,on0,os1,on1,quantity,invoice,custom) values ('".$txn_id."','".$_POST[$itemnumber]."','".$_POST[$itemname]."','".$_POST[$on0]."','".$_POST[$os0]."','".$_POST[$on1]."','".$_POST[$os1]."','".$_POST[$quantity]."','".$invoice."','".$custom."')";
         $result = mysql_query($struery) or die("Cart - paypal_cart_info, Query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());

     }
    }



    else{
     $strQuery = "insert into paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,country,mc_gross,mc_fee,itemnumber,itemname,os0,on0,os1,on1,quantity,memo,paymenttype,paymentdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,datecreation) values ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_street."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."','".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$item_number."','".$item_name."','".$option_name1."','".$option_selection1."','".$option_name2."','".$option_selection2."','".$quantity."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')";
     $result = mysql_query("insert into paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,country,mc_gross,mc_fee,itemnumber,itemname,os0,on0,os1,on1,quantity,memo,paymenttype,paymentdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,datecreation) values ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_street."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."','".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$item_number."','".$item_name."','".$option_name1."','".$option_selection1."','".$option_name2."','".$option_selection2."','".$quantity."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')") or die("Default - paypal_payment_info, Query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
    }


    // send an email in any case
 echo "Verified";
     mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED IPN", "$res\n $req\n $strQuery\n $struery\n  $strQuery2");
}
else {
// send an email
mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED DUPLICATED TRANSACTION", "$res\n $req \n $strQuery\n $struery\n  $strQuery2");
}

    //subscription handling branch
    if ( $txn_type == "subscr_signup"  ||  $txn_type == "subscr_payment"  ) {

      // insert subscriber payment info into paypal_payment_info table
      $strQuery = "insert into paypal_payment_info(paymentstatus,buyer_email,firstname,lastname,street,city,state,zipcode,country,mc_gross,mc_fee,memo,paymenttype,paymentdate,txnid,pendingreason,reasoncode,tax,datecreation) values ('".$payment_status."','".$payer_email."','".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$address_street."','".$address_city."','".$address_state."','".$address_zip."','".$address_country."','".$mc_gross."','".$mc_fee."','".$memo."','".$payment_type."','".$payment_date."','".$txn_id."','".$pending_reason."','".$reason_code."','".$tax."','".$fecha."')";
      $result = mysql_query($strQuery) or die("Subscription - paypal_payment_info, Query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());


         // insert subscriber info into paypal_subscription_info table
        $strQuery2 = "insert into paypal_subscription_info(subscr_id , sub_event, subscr_date ,subscr_effective,period1,period2, period3, amount1 ,amount2 ,amount3,  mc_amount1,  mc_amount2,  mc_amount3, recurring, reattempt,retry_at, recur_times, username ,password, payment_txn_id, subscriber_emailaddress, datecreation) values ('".$subscr_id."', '".$txn_type."','".$subscr_date."','".$subscr_effective."','".$period1."','".$period2."','".$period3."','".$amount1."','".$amount2."','".$amount3."','".$mc_amount1."','".$mc_amount2."','".$mc_amount3."','".$recurring."','".$reattempt."','".$retry_at."','".$recur_times."','".$username."','".$password."', '".$txn_id."','".$payer_email."','".$fecha."')";
        $result = mysql_query($strQuery2) or die("Subscription - paypal_subscription_info, Query failed:<br>" . mysql_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());


             mail($notify_email, "VERIFIED IPN", "$res\n $req\n $strQuery\n $struery\n  $strQuery2");

    }
}

// if the IPN POST was 'INVALID'...do this


else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
// log for manual investigation

mail($notify_email, "INVALID IPN", "$res\n $req");
}
}
fclose ($fp);
}
```

?>

Comment: On your example, what would I do with the original form _POST variables? as I currently use them to update the database for new events (event name, id, participants, contact details etc.). I know that the PayPal API has on1 os1 through to 9 but if I have more than say 20 "non paypal related" variables to post, what would be the easiest way?

Comment: If I'm not able to pass those variables from my original form to the simple 'buy now' paypal button page then to paypal then back to my website after payment is complete... then I guess I'll need to update the database first and add "verified = 1" column after user completes payment?

Comment: So it looks like I can't post the original "user form" variables to PayPal (and have PayPal return them to IPN - plus that'd just be a pointless passing all those variables around). Thus I need to just update the column after payment and change some other files to check for 'if verified'

Comment: OK now I seem to have IPN working and updating a DB table for payments (to store txn_id etc.) however I'm not sure where/how I should update my other table with the other variables (that I can't really post to paypal as they'd exceed 256 characters for custom).

Comment: Could try posting them over using some of the other PayPal variables that are available that you are not using.  You could store them temporarily in your database until the merchant completes the purchase and then retrieve them from the database and use them as needed then.  If they don't return after a period of time, you could remove them.  Similar to storing a temp session in the database.

Comment: Hmm ok thanks @PP_MTS_Chad - I've got it working by setting the variables in the DB first, then after payment complete, I set the column to verified, might change it at a later date but this was easiest to set-up.